# Ссылка на всю кнопку меню

Tags: html, css

Помогите, не получается.
Как сделать чтобы на всей кнопке в меню при наведении была бы ссылка?

```
.nav-pills li.menu_new {
padding: 16px 10px 14px;
border-left: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
height: 45px;
line-height: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Добавить `padding` ссылке, а не `<li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поправьте файл css

```
 .nav-pills li.menu_new {
/* padding: 16px 10px 14px; */ это  тут удаляем
border-left: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
height: 45px;
line-height: 45px;
}

.nav-pills li a {
line-height: 1;
color: #3f4142;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
padding: 16px 10px 14px;// а тут добавляем
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь понял!